# References for Probit and Logistic Regression

Tags: references

I am looking for a book that essentially covers probit and logistic regression. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAGE publishes a [reference](http://www.sagepub.com/textbooks/Book11401) on the two, for both ordered and multinomial models. It's short, inexpensive, approachable and to the point.